# C++ fault detecting collisions in 2d array

Tags: c++, debugging

I am working on a simple tic tac toe game. I have some errors on my `checkCollision` function. Here is the function:

```
void checkCollision(const int rows, const int cols, char ticTacToe [][3])
{
    //code to check for collision between x and o
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (ticTacToe[row][col] != '.') 
            {
                std::cout << "Collision detected. Please try again.\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `main` function.

```
int main()
{

    //create 2d array
    char ticTacToe[3][3] = { 
        {'.', '.', '.'},
        {'.', '.', '.'},
        {'.', '.', '.'},
    };

    //declare variables
    const int numRows{ 3 };
    const int numCols{ 3 };
    const int playerOne{ 1 };
    const int playerTwo{ 2 };
    int rowCordinate{};
    int colCordinate{};
    bool hasWon{};

    //print grid
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
        {
            std::cout << ticTacToe[row][col];
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    //game loop
    do {
        std::cout << "\nPlayer one, please put in a row co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> rowCordinate;

        std::cout << "\nPut in a column co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> colCordinate;

        checkCollision(numRows, numCols, ticTacToe);
        changeArray(numRows, numCols, rowCordinate, colCordinate, ticTacToe, playerOne);
        

        std::cout << "\nPlayer two, please put in a row co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> rowCordinate;

        std::cout << "\nPut in a column co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> colCordinate;

        checkCollision(numRows, numCols, ticTacToe);
        changeArray(numRows, numCols, rowCordinate, colCordinate, ticTacToe, playerTwo);
        
    } while (!hasWon);

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I input a row and column coordinate after the first loop, it tells me there's a collision. It feels like a quirk of how arrays work in C++ but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Comment: `checkCollision` checks whether there is any element that isn't `'.'` not whether a specific element isn't `'.'`

Comment: Please write the function for ChangeArray. We can help you at least when you add necessary information to enable the operation. Debugging is not possible in the current state.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to specifically check for if the space at `rowCordinate`, `colCordinate` is occupied (and probably disallow the user from choosing that point). What if you try something like:

```
bool checkCollision(const size_t row, const size_t col, char ticTacToe [][3])
{
    return ticTacToe[row][col] != '.';
}
```

then in the main loop you would need to change the user input section to something like:

```
//game loop
do {
    // player 1 input
    while (true) {
        // get user input
        std::cout << "\nPlayer one, please put in a row co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> rowCordinate;

        std::cout << "\nPut in a column co-ordinate:\t";
        std::cin >> colCordinate;

        // if the user selected a valid spot, change the array and move on
        if (!checkCollision(rowCordinate, colCordinate, ticTacToe)) {
            changeArray(numRows, numCols, rowCordinate, colCordinate, ticTacToe, playerTwo);
            break;
        }
        
        // otherwise print a message and keep looping
        std::cout << "Collision detected. Please try again.\n";
    }
    
    // player 2 input
    ...
```